# How to insert translated string in the display twig operator

Tags: symfony, twig

I have created a twig function which has a parameter 'message'. The value of this parameter should be a translation.

I thought I could do like that but no. Problem of syntax maybe :

```
{{ attention ('{
        "message":"' ~ {% trans %}generalites.projectkit.attention{% endtrans %} ~ '"
   }')
}}
```

{% trans %} is not displayed correctly in IDE and I have this error message :

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses 
(unexpected token "operator" of value "%")
```

Can you help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
{{ attention | trans({
        "message": "'" ~ 'generalites.projectkit.attention' | trans ~ "'"
   })
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to put `{% %}` inside `{{ }}` in twig.

Replace the

```
{% trans %}generalites.projectkit.attention{% endtrans %}
```

with

```
generalites.projectkit.attention|trans
```

Comment: it tells me that it does not know the generalites variable